# Storing Database Locally in File/Folder

Tags: database

I'm in the middle of doing a personal project and would like to create a system of three components.

1. A simple form application that would allow the user to input data into a database.
2. A database of multiple tables.
3. An excel spreadsheet that queries the database.

At this point in the project, there is a desire for the database to be stored on the PC of the person working on the project and for all three components of the project to have the ability to be zipped up in a folder and emailed around. I know how to code well enough to query databases from applications and excel, but how can I go about creating a database that can be stored in a specific folder so it can be emailed around?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into sql compact edition

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact

http://xldennis.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/using-sql-server-compact-edition-database-with-excel/

MS Access might also be an option here.